# TeamCity CompileSwift errors

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, teamcity

We had TeamCity set up under another dev in xcode. We have a new dev and we've changed the provisional profile and certificates, now we have this error in the TeamCity build.

> [16:48:27]** BUILD FAILED **
>
> [16:48:27]
>
> [16:48:27]
>
> [16:48:27]The following build commands failed:
>
> [16:48:27] CompileSwift normal armv7
>
> [16:48:27] CompileSwiftSources normal armv7
>   com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>
> [16:48:27] CompileSwift normal arm64
>
> [16:48:27](3 failures)
>
> [16:48:48]** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> [16:48:48]
>
> [16:48:48]
>
> [16:48:48]The following build commands failed:
>
> [16:48:48] CompileSwift normal arm64
>
> [16:48:48] CompileSwiftSources normal arm64
>   com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>
> [16:48:48] CompileSwift normal armv7
>
> [16:48:48](3 failures)
>
> [16:48:48]error: archive not found at path
>   '/TeamCity/buildAgentCheckin/work/9bf31a8ed4fa36ca/TaskManager/Build/AssociatedApp.xcarchive'
>
> [16:48:48]Process exited with code 65

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are seeing this, we found the solution.

It turns out that we had an issue with three things:

1. Hidden bug that didn't reveal itself until we got a closer look at build log by trying to build from the server computer (instead of remotely as our CI/CD flow normally does). The general arm64 was simply saying the compiler was failing, so we had to clean build and check the code to see what's was going on.
2. The Deployment/Release build configuration (Provisioning Profiles and Certificates) and
3. The VCS roots in TeamCity.

We found the computer on which the developer the original TeamCity server, stopped the server, looked at the scripts and ran the script that kept failing (makeIpa.sh) and we got more detailed error messages running the script.

We then followed the errors the script gave us when we executed in the Terminal, and then we finally got the build to compile successfully.

We then had to resolve certificate issues to allow for deployment to TeamCity.

We did that by deleting all the certificates, profiles, and apple ID's from xcode on the server computer, and then setting it up again to allow access.

After this, the build and archive was successful, but then we kept having the wrong version of our app ship out from TeamCity to production.

We then looked at the VCS roots and realized the VCS root configuration was set to publish a branch that was broken.

Hope this info helps!